# Video Problem & Performance Issues

Tags: 14.04, ati, graphics, video, fglrx

I have an Acer Aspire E1-522 laptop with following configuration :

`AMD Quad-Core Processor A6-5200 (2.0 GHz)
 AMD Radeon`<sup>`TM`</sup>`HD 8400
 4 GB DDR3 RAM
 15.6" Display (1366*768)`

I am running **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**. I am facing problems not only with video playback but overall performance.
This is a screenshot of movie playback, there is an overlay from other video file.

> [image: Screenshot from movie Noah, the Colombia part is from other movie]

The problem keeps persisting until I either **logout** or **restart** & does not depend on what player I use (currently VLC & mplayer)

Also, I am experiencing a problem slowdown which is negligible in Linux Mint (Booted from USB drive). Firefox and other apps randomly get greyed out and then start responding later. In very rare cases, the laptop would shut down and it also eats up a lot of CPU resources.

**Output of `df -h` :**

```
 /dev/sda10       40G   18G   20G  48% /
 none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
 udev            1.7G  4.0K  1.7G   1% /dev
 tmpfs           334M  1.5M  332M   1% /run
 none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
 none            1.7G  752K  1.7G   1% /run/shm
 none            100M   48K  100M   1% /run/user
 /dev/sda2        86G   31G   55G  36% /media/rishbh/Win
 /dev/sda5       100G   40G   61G  40% /media/rishbh/Gaming
 /dev/sda6       120G  118G  2.9G  98% /media/rishbh/Media
 /dev/sda7        80G   52G   29G  64% /media/rishbh/Impfiles
 /dev/sda8        12G  9.5G  2.6G  79% /media/rishbh/AndroidDev
 /dev/sda9        29G  6.0G   23G  22% /media/rishbh/Docs
 /dev/sda11      231M   40M  180M  19% /boot
 /dev/sr0        2.4G  2.4G     0 100% /media/rishbh/ResourceCD
```

**Output of `iostat` :**

```
 Linux 3.16.0-28-generic (rishbh-Aspire-E1-522)     Friday 02 January 2015  _x86_64_    (4 CPU)

 avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           16.94    0.01    2.32    0.63    0.00   80.09

 Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
 sda               6.52       100.77       112.81    1051348    1177010
 scd0              0.00         0.01         0.00         56          0
```

How do I get rid of these problems **without** reinstalling Ubuntu again?

Comment: Which version of fglrx do you have installed? For me, the newest version from AMD's website could resolve some problems.

Comment: @the_Seppi :
`fglrx-updates/trusty,now 2:13.350.1-0ubuntu2 amd64`

Comment: (unrelated, but not helping the video output neither:) 98% full on the media partition!  Ubuntu has less problems with fragmentation then Windows *provided it has more then 5%* on the partition available as free space.  (which you must have 'tweaked', as that is the standard)

Comment: Had some problem, kind of solved it by changing the video-output in mplayer config from `vo=xv`to `vo=gl`